# android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-recyclerview

I'm taking pictures by camera, adding them to ArrayList as Bitmap. I have recyclerView that is showing taken images. I want to have an alertdialog, that shows clicked image with option to delete. I'm having a problem with setting custom layout to AlertDialog. When I click on image, app crashes and error says

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Error point to this row of code

> View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, (ViewGroup) view,false);
>                   imageDialog.setView(viewInflated);

but I'm not sure what I should do. I tried to change (ViewGroup) to something else but with no luck.

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

private  List<Bitmap> fotky;
private Bitmap foto;

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    foto = fotky.get(position);
    holder.photo.setImageBitmap(foto);
    holder.photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder imageDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            imageDialog.setTitle("Image");
            View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, (ViewGroup) view,false);
            imageDialog.setView(viewInflated);
            ImageView image = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.fotka);
            image.setImageBitmap(foto);
            imageDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();

                }
            });
            imageDialog.setNegativeButton("delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    remove(position);
                }
            });
            imageDialog.show();

            //TODO tady ukázat full image s možností smazání

            //remove(position);
        }



    });

}

public void add(int position, Bitmap item) {
    fotky.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position) {
    fotky.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, fotky.size());
}

public Adapter(List<Bitmap> myDataset) {
    fotky = myDataset;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fotky.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView photo;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

}
```

**Dialog_image.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fotka"
    android:contentDescription="photo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind this crash is you have setup click listener on `holder.photo` which is of type `AppCompatImageView`. inside onClick block you are typecasting it to `ViewGroup`.

Change it to following.

```
View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_image, null);
```

It should work.